# Revert pull to previous commit

Tags: git, github

I am working on GIT.

I was working on a branch named branch1 and I accidentaly pulled other branch and I believe it merged automatically. So the problem is I want to maintain two different branches in my local repo.

So here is my question,
Pulling from branch2 in branch1 in my local repo would it auto-merge?
If it auto-merges how can I undo the last pull and have my last commit?

Answer (score 0):

`git pull branch2` when you are on branch 1 would result in a merge.  `git pull` is a combination command of `git fetch` and in your case `git merge`.

In order to undo the changes look at your log with `git log`.  You should see a commit that has a message similar to "Merge branch 'branch2' into 'branch1".

That commit is the one that performed the merge.  Below the SHA for this commit will be an entry `Merge: <partial sha> <partial sha>`.  This line tells you the two commits that were combined in the merge.  One will be the latest commit from branch2 that you pulled in.  The other will be the latest commit on your branch.  When you have determined which commit that you want, you can use `git reset --hard` to put your branch at that point removing everything that was merged in.

`git reset --hard` is not recoverable so if you are worried about doing it wrong, create a new branch with all the changes via `git branch backupBranch` so you don't lose anything if you `reset --hard` at the wrong point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured I would make a `git stash` and ignore  delete it off. I hope I am not wrong.